# Terraform:log export sink throws this error "permission denied on bucket" after properly working for sometime

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-cloud-logging

I am trying to export log from source to a destination project, in GCP. I have used the below Terraform code to create logsink and have assigned relevant permissions to unique_writer_identity. It works fine for the first 15 to 20 mins then I received a mail saying "log_bucket_permission_denied". To find whats going wrong I did Terraform plan on the same deployment it reports service accounts created through sinks got changed and those service account doesn't have the assigned permissions, if this is why it stops working after 15 mins, What could be done to make this work without failing after sometime? Kindly help me out. Thanks

"Terraform Plan" after 15 mins of deployment:

```
Note: Objects have changed outside of Terraform

Terraform detected the following changes made outside of Terraform since the last "terraform apply":

  # google_project_iam_binding.config_writer_audit_log_service_account["roles/logging.fieldAccessor"] has been changed

  ~ resource "google_project_iam_binding" "config_writer_audit_log_service_account" {

      ~ etag    = "XXXXXXXX=" -> "YYYYYYYYY="

        id      = "project_id/roles/logging.fieldAccessor"

        # (3 unchanged attributes hidden)

    }
  # google_project_iam_binding.config_writer_audit_log_service_account["roles/logging.logWriter"] has been changed

  ~ resource "google_project_iam_binding" "config_writer_audit_log_service_account" {

      ~ etag    = "XXXXXXXX=" -> "YYYYYYYYY="

        id      = "project_id/roles/logging.logWriter"

        # (3 unchanged attributes hidden)

    }
    Terrraform will make the following changes:
    
google_project_iam_binding.config_writer_audit_service_account["roles/logging.logWriter"] will be updated in-place


  ~ resource "google_project_iam_binding" "config_writer_audit_service_account" {

        id      = ""

      ~ members = [

          - "serviceAccount:XXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXX@gcp-sa-logging.iam.gserviceaccount.com",

          + "serviceAccount:XXXXXXXXXX-YYYYYY@gcp-sa-logging.iam.gserviceaccount.com",

        ]

        # (3 unchanged attributes hidden)
    }

    ....and some more
```

CODE:

```
    

#Audit Log Sink1 --> Audit Logs to  Log Bucket
resource "google_logging_project_sink" "sink_logging_audit_log_bucket" {

  name       = "${var.project_id}_ingest_audit_log_bucket_test"

  project    = var.project_id

  description = "Logging Sink for Audit"

  destination = "logging.googleapis.com/${google_logging_project_bucket_config.logging_sink_audit_test.id}"

  filter="LOG_ID(cloudaudit.googleapis.com/activity) OR LOG_ID(externalaudit.googleapis.com/activity) OR LOG_ID(cloudaudit.googleapis.com/system_event) OR LOG_ID(externalaudit.googleapis.com/system_event) OR LOG_ID(cloudaudit.googleapis.com/access_transparency) OR LOG_ID(externalaudit.googleapis.com/access_transparency)"
  unique_writer_identity = true
}


###log bucket

resource "google_logging_project_bucket_config" "logging_sink_audit_test" {

    project    = var.common_project_id

    location   = var.location 

    retention_days = 30

    bucket_id = "log-test-bucket_test"

}
resource "google_project_iam_binding" "object_creator_log_audit_test" {

  project    = var.common_project_id

  role = "roles/storage.objectCreator"


  members = [
    google_logging_project_sink.sink_logging_audit_log_bucket.writer_identity 
    
  ]
}
resource "google_project_iam_binding" "log_bucket_Writer_audit_log_test" {

    project    = var.common_project_id

    role = "roles/logging.bucketWriter"


  members = [
    google_logging_project_sink.sink_logging_audit_log_bucket.writer_identity 

    
  ]
}
resource "google_project_iam_binding" "log_config_Writer_audit_test" {
    project    = var.common_project_id
    role = "roles/logging.configWriter"
  members = [
    google_logging_project_sink.sink_logging_audit_log_bucket.writer_identity 

    
  ]
}
resource "google_project_iam_binding" "logging_Writer_audit_test" {
    project    = var.common_project_id
    role = "roles/logging.logWriter"
  members = [
    google_logging_project_sink.sink_logging_audit_log_bucket.writer_identity 

    
  ]

}
```

Comment: This tells me something is changing permissions (access control). Look in the audit logs for activity. Do you have an ORG policy or a Cloud Function enforcing rules such as **logging field-level access control**?

Comment: only this ORG policy is enforced "iam.disableCrossProjectServiceAccountUsage",dont have cloud functions.

Comment: Were you able to figure out why this is happening? I am facing the same problem. Any suggestion son the fix?